# What happens to a moot flag?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088505/how-linq-query-will-work-on-xml) was justifiably put on hold earlier today. Not too long after, the OP edited their question and added enough details to put it back on track.

Before that happened, I posted the following comment in response to the OP asking why his post was getting downvoted:

> Removed downvote and flagging for a mod to reevaluate if your edit makes it a better suited for SO. Andrew Barber's note sums up the reason for the downvotes. Don't take it personally, it's only a matter of getting the better questions on the front page.

And then flagged the post for moderator attention, mentioning that the OP had modified their post.

Now the flag is still pending review, but in the meantime another mod has reopened the question, people posted answers and the OP ended up accepting one... which leaves me with a moot flag pending review.

What happens then?

Have I done well, to:

1. Post this comment in the first place;
2. Flag the question for moderator attention, so the question could be reopened.

Comment: Kudos for the effort, by the way. And just a tiny little point to add; The on-hold explanation boxes are actually added by the on-hold system itself, rather than manually. It is based on some menu options. I can only take credit for choosing a helpful menu option, therefore! Also, in case you are not aware of this, too; after a certain level of reputation, normal users can also vote to put questions on-hold; it takes five that way. (Diamond moderators can do it unilaterally)

Comment: Wow there's some *wizardry* going on under the hood there, SO/SE is even more awesome than I thought!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It gets [mootinated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/153001/mootinator). No?

Generally it will get dismissed as helpful whenever a moderator gets around to reviewing it (as has been done now). We get a big red notice box to the right that indicates that the post was reopened, so it's pretty hard to "accidentally" decline flags like these.

Just a note though, a moderator didn't reopen the question. It was reopened by five members of the community. If a moderator had reopened the question, the flag would have gotten dismissed as helpful by the moderator who reopened it.

Comment: Fair enough - thanks! ...btw that dynamic pic is FREAKY!

Comment: Insert clever and/or somehow insightful comment here.

Comment: @mootinator Really, you just needed to insert your name.